# If the aircraft has no inertia, how will it move after losing power?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, inertia, aircraft

If the aircraft has no inertia, how will it move after losing power? I think because of the aerodynamic force, the aircraft stopped moving immediately. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by having no inertia?

Comment: So, the aircraft has no inertia how exactly?

Comment: @bemjanim Suppose the mass of the aircraft is zero and there is no inertia.

Comment: @M.Enns Suppose the mass of the aircraft is zero and there is no inertia.

Answer (score 2):

Having no inertia means having no mass.

That changes everything. When it is pushed forward by engine force (or any other force), it will move with infinite acceleration due to Newton's 2nd law, reaching infinite speed*  - when the forwards-force stops, air drag, as you mention, will cause an infinite deceleration and immediately stop it.

This is all a theoretical extreme. No-mass (and thus no-inertia) objects do not exist and are theoretically absurd cases.**

---

<sup>* "Infinite speed" might be the speed of light.</sup>

<sup>** We only talk about no-mass *particles*, such as a photon, which actually does move at highest possible speed, namely the speed of light.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An airplane without inertia cannot exist.  It is a thought experiment that fails as fast as asking what color a [teapot in orbit around Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot) is.

All objects governed by Newton's laws have mass.  There are massless things, such as photons.  They are not governed by Netwon's laws, and I don't think you intended to turn your airplane into a beam of light.  Regardless, the concept of force as defined in Newton's laws requires there to be momentum.  Without it, we don't use Newton's laws  nor the concepts described in them.

Now what we can do is ask what would happen if an airplane suddenly lost **nearly** all of its mass for some unspecified reason (such that its mass is almost but not quite zero), and maintained its velocity during that process.  We can ask what happens to its velocity after that.

And the answer to that question lines up with your intuition.  Aerodynamic forces will *very* quickly reduce its velocity to nearly zero.  You can experience this yourself by getting in the passenger seat of a car driving 45 mph and throwing a whiffle ball out of the window.  Its velocity will drop dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

An aircraft has mass $m$, and therefore inertia. Hence any force   (including the aerodynamic force) according to Newton's $F=ma$ is not able to stop the aircraft immediately.

Comment: Suppose the mass of the aircraft is zero and there is no inertia.